# RFC791, MTU and a minimum packet size

Tags: networking, ip

I was reading rfc791 and trying to understand the relations with MTU as well as with the minimum packet size for IPv4. Here are two quotes from the rfc:

```
"All hosts must be prepared to accept datagrams of up to 576 octets (whether they arrive whole or in fragments)."
```

And

```
"Every internet module must be able to forward a datagram of 68 octets without further fragmentation.  This is because an internet header may be up to 60 octets, and the minimum fragment is 8 octets."
```

Do I understand correctly that first related only to *hosts*, i.e. only hosts must be able to process minimum packet size of 576 bytes, while the second statement defines the mi packet size for a router? But of so, then it is possible to have a router not being able to receive a packet of 68 bytes for *himself* ?

Or I'm missing something very fundamental?

Thanks.
Mark

Answer (score 1):

The 576 octet is a "least maximum". In other words, a host needs to be prepared to have a maximum packet size of no less than 576 octets. It can be bigger than that, such as the 1518 limit used by most (non-jumbo) Ethernet devices, but not any smaller.

Anything that is set up to forward packets must not split them into chunks of less than 68 octets.

Comment: I don't understand what packet size should be when a router (forwarding entity with min 68b chunks) also acts as a host (576b min.), consider this:

A - R1 - R2 - B.

Host A sends long packet to R2, assume R1 splits it in 68b chunks, therefore it's going to deliver 68b not 576b to the host R2 (in this scenario R2 is a host). In my opinion, this contradicts to RFC. I surely misunderstand something.

Comment: lol I just set my mtu to 25 and knocked my linux box off the internet forever! Should have checked SO first!!!

Answer (score 1):

By standard, 576 Bytes is "minimum MTU" supported over IP infrastructure. This means, any host/router must support this value and any IP packets can be smaller than 576 Bytes (atleast 68 Bytes) which can move IP world without fragmentation.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

The first relates to accepting; the second relates to forwarding.

> then it is possible to have a router not being able to receive a packet of 68 bytes for himself

That doesn't make any sense. A host must be able to accept datagrams of up to 576 octets.

Comment: But then two directly connected hosts on a link with MTU 68 bytes, which is legal, would not be able to exchange datagrams ?

Comment: Why not? They could fragment them into 68-byte packets.